# ASP.NET Core Identity and Web API for Angular front end

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

We are building an application with `Angular 10` based front-end and `.NET Core 3.1` based `Web APIs`. For `Authentication` and `Authorization` we want to use `ASP.NET Core Identity`. I want to know if we can have `Identity` system integrated with our `Web API` project and use `Authentication` method via `Web APIs` to generate `JWT` and later `Authorization`. I am wondering if this is good approach to follow or there is any security flaw in this approach. I get this doubt because I have read somewhere that the `Authentication` must be over server rendered pages instead of `JavaScript` based front-ends.

Comment: Authentication should be done on the backend, but the page doesnt need to be rendered in the backend. Simply make sure to limit sensetive information to api calls and dont bundle them with the frontend application. And yes ASP.NET Core Identity is the way to go.

Comment: Does this mean that we must build a separate application using `ASP.NET Core MVC` or `Angular` to render the `Authentication` pages? or maybe I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: That depends on your situation. But normally i dont see why you canot have login page in your angular application. You must of course send the login request to the api from that form.

Comment: I am trying to get the gist of `dont bundle them with the frontend application` as the SPAs will contain the entire application in browser when I create Login page in Angular, it will have the API paths bundled with it.

Comment: Take a look at IdentityServer. It provides all the infrastructure and quick starts. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/big_picture.html

Comment: Login is generally done via OAuth, which uses redirects. The IdentityServer docs show how to use a JS client to integrate this flow with a SPA like Angular.

Comment: I think identity server is overkill for a single site. If you are developing multiple different angular apps then a identiprovider like that might be useful though.

Comment: We are having single application and we will go with the ASP.NET Core Identity as @Achtung suggests.